# ¿Entity Framework Core 3 es compatible con MySQL o MariaDb?

Tags: c#, mysql, mariadb, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Saludos he estado investigando si es posible utilizar una una base de datos mysql con Entity Framework core y hasta ahora he encontrado que usando un paquete llamado "pomelo" es como podría usarlo, en la documentación de mysql solo soporta hasta la versión (2.1) de net core y revisando la documentación de Microsoft no me aparece como proveedor compatible mysql solo SQL server y Sqlite [image: documentación Microsoft]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si revisamos la lista de proveedores

[Database Providers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)

Es cierto lo que comentas acerca de `Pomelo` como implementador de la libreria para `MySql`

Puedes utilizar la libreria agregando la referencia mediante nuget

[Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql)

Nota: Presiona en el link que dice `Overview` para ver la tabla de proveedores no te quedes solo con el arbol que arma el menu, lees la documentacion por dentro